# Parsing a peculiar legal sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

A certain Government Order [goes](https://thc.nic.in/Tripura%20State%20Lagislation%20Rules/The%20Tripura%20Subordinate%20Civil%20Courts%20Ministerial%20Establishment%20.pdf) (Section 2a) —

> These rules shall not apply to the appointment of persons to ministerial posts in the Civil Courts subordinate to the High Court/Khas Adalat of Judicature for Independent Tripura in the process of integration of services of the pre-reorganization Independent State of Tripura in accordance with the rules and Govt. Orders regulating such integration of services.

What does this hell of a sentence even mean? I am pretty sure that this is ungrammatical.

For necessary background:

- [Tripura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura) was a quasi-independent [princely state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princely_state) that had [acceded to India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura_Merger_Agreement) sixteen years before this Order was issued.
- Independent Tripura used to have a "Khas Adalat of Judicature" (i.e. the High Court). Within a year of accession, India invested the powers of the Court in the Judicial Commissioner but I am not sure if the institution and courts under it — whose powers were similarly invested elsewhere —  maintained some kind of shadowy presence in the years afterward. They were never abolished *explicitly* unlike in the case of many other princely states.

Comment: This rules shall not apply to [*ministerial posts in the Civil Courts subordinate to the High Court/Khas Adalat of Judicature for Independent Tripura*] in [*the process of integration of services of the pre-reorganization Independent State of Tripura*] in [*in accordance with the rules and Governement Orders regulating such integration of services*]. The sentence is grammatically correct, but poorly formulated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because interpreting legal documents is off-topic on ELU as it could possibly expose the interpreter to legal action, and often legalese departs from standard English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This *entire* law has been abrogated some 70 years ago. So, I doubt that anybody will care to subject the interpreter to legal action notwithstanding the frivolous nature of it of somebody did. I seek to understand it for my own curiosity and paranoia does not serve any purpose. This is plainly clumsy English, I believe.

Comment: @AvadaMouse, the quoted text is syntactically ambiguous, because too much is being squeezed into a single sentence, without adequate punctuation. That's all that can be said about it so far as English language and usage (the topic of this site) is concerned; it is outside the scope of this site to try to guess the **intended** meaning of that syntactically ambiguous sentence, or to reconstruct it on the basis of extraneous historical data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no legal expert, but I read it as:

1. There are some courts that are the Civil Courts subordinate to the "High Court/Khas Adalat of Judicature for Independent Tripura."
2. Some people are getting appointed to ministerial posts in those courts.
3. Those appointments are happening as part of the process of integrating all the services of the Independent State of Tripura, as they existed prior to the ongoing reorganization, into the new regime.
4. These appointments are happening in accordance with the regulations covering that integration process.
5. **The sentence is saying that "these rules" rules don't apply to appointments of this kind, i.e. to the ones that are mere parts of the integrating/reorganizing the old institutions into the new system.**

That said, I might be wrong about (4): (Alternatively, it could be saying, not that the appointments are in accordance with the regulations, but that the *non-application of the rules* is in accordance with those regulations. Presumably reading these regulations--the "rules and Govt. Orders" it mentions, which I think aren't identical to the rules mentioned at the start of the sentences--would help settle this.

On either reading, though, it's establishing a special exception to the rules for putting new people in those existing subordinate courts as part of the integration process; the personnel of the courts may change, but they aren't being abolished by this agreement, so far as I can tell.